# How to get a “refresh” right click action?

Tags: 14.04, nautilus

I'm new to Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. I want a 'refresh' option, like in Windows when you right click on desktop. Can anyone help me to get that option in Ubuntu?

Comment: it'll make no sense... I'm asuming you just got used to this Windows feature and automatically want to click it. ;)

Comment: Ctrl + R? it's also faster then right-click - select - click.

Comment: Do you mean like F5?